# Юзер онлайн или офлайн на сайте

Tags: база-данных

Всем привет, хочу понять как сделать проверку на онлайн юзера на сайте, чтобы другие тоже могли видеть. Хотел сделать одним способом, каждые например 30секунд сайт отправляет запрос на сервер, где заносит в базу данных информацию что юзер онлайн, но вот когда юзер ушел с сайта, сайт ни какие запросы не посылает, а в базе данных так и осталось что он онлайн. Есть способы как это решить или есть более удобные способы?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть 3 варианта:

1. Использование WebSocket. Пока держится соединение - пользователь онлайн
2. После любого действия пользователя на сайте обновляешь его статус "онлайн"
3. Проверка жив ли он с помощью Ajax. Не тестил, но слышал, что некоторые так делают

Comment: Еще можно  добавить слушалку на движение мыши/ввод клавиатуры. Если пользователь последнюю минуту ничего не делал, то изменить статус на  "неактивен"